# Best way to create a portable SSD install of Linux

Tags: linux, system-installation

What is the easiest way to create a truly portable installation of Ubuntu (or any other flavor for that matter)? I am able to create an installation of Ubuntu on an external drive using macOS and balenaEtcher but then I am left with Grub controlling the boot process. Is there a way to eliminate Grub from macOS and still be left with an external hard drive that can boot independently?

Comment: just for clarification, this is about booting computers that are **exclusively** x86_64 apple computers, right?

Comment: Two easy ways: 1. Make a **persistent live system** with [**mkusb**](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb); 2. Extract and clone **Ubuntu Server from a compressed image file** and when booted into it, install a desktop environment if you wish. See [**this link**](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2474692) to a thread at the Ubuntu Forums.